# What happens when you have two media queries that are at the same size?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Lets you say you have two media queries on an element that both match. How do you know which one wins?

For example, let's say you have a media query that sets a rectangle to be red at LESS than or equal to 500 pixels and you a media query that makes it blue at MORE than or EQUAL to 500 pixels. Which one wins? And let's say you have a phone that is 500 pixels wide.

```css
hr {
  width: 400px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.rect {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .rect {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
}

/* larger content */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .rect {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  Here is a div
</div>

<hr width="500px">
```

I would like to setup proper media break points. Do I need to rewrite them? Should they be min-width 501px and so on?

Comment: It's what ever gets written in your css last. Remember CSS gets read from top to bottom so whatever the latest styles are gets priority.

Comment: Both will work. If the properties in them are the same, then those below in the code will be applied.

Comment: I always run into this issue when I use max-width for media queries so now I always use min-width

Answer (score 2):

Normally it's the style declaration that comes last in the code that "wins" (is applied!). You can set !important on a style declaration, but IMHO that is toss-up and sometimes doesn't work. I 'think' id styles will have more importance over class styles, but I do know you can set multiple class name styles more influential.

Code not tested:

```css
#less_important {
   background : green;
   width : 50px;
   height : 50px;
}


.blue {
    background : blue;
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
}


.red {
   background : red;
   border : 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<div id = "less_important" class = "blue">

</div>


<div class = "blue red">

</div>

<div class = "red blue">

</div>


</html>
```

Move the style .red and .blue in the code and see what happens to understand

Answer (score 1):

CSS mean Cascading Style Sheets.
Definition of *cascade*:
"Something arranged or occurring in a series or in a succession of stages so that each stage derives from or acts upon the product of the preceding."

So, whatever comes after in the cascade will overwrite the previous.

Yes, you should set the one with min-width to 401.

Comment: Ok so last one at same specificity wins and min width and max width are less and equal to and more and equal to.

Comment: The problem with setting the min-width to 401 is that sub-pixel rendering (in Firefox at least) means that styling can fall into the gap. See [Example 17 from the media queries level 4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#example-e45f87c2)